# My twitter typehead and django-haystack solr config is not returning any results

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, solr

Not very good with anything javascript, jquery. I am trying to return results from solr and run it through the typehead and have a dropdown list in a google or bing type fashion. Iv'e been kinda messing around with it but I'm deadlocked. I created a drop down list but it doesn't look nice. Heres my code

views.py

```
def search_title(request):
  posts = SearchQuerySet().models(Post).autocomplete(content_auto=request.GET.get('search_text', ''))
  context = {
    "posts": posts
  }
# context.update(csrf(request))
return render(request, "posts/ajax_search.html", {"posts": posts})
```

posts/urls.py

```
   urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^$', post_list, name='list'),
   ......
   url(r'^search_f/$', search_title),
   ....
]
```

ajax_search.html

```
{% if posts.count > 0 %}

{% for post in posts %}
<div><a href="{% url 'posts:detail' post.slug %}" class="list-group-item">{{    post.title }}</a></div>
{% endfor %}

{% else %}
<li class="list-group-item"> None to show</li>
{% endif %}
```

snippet of nav.html

```
 <form method="GET" action="{% url 'posts:search-page' %}"  class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
      <div>
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" name="q" id="search" placeholder="search" value="{{ request.GET.q }}">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">search</button>
          </span>
        </div><!-- /input-group -->

        <div class="list-group" id="search-results" style="margin: 5px 0 0 0; width: 172px">
        </div>

      </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
    </form>
```

ajax.js

```
    $(function(){

    $('#search').keyup(function() {

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/posts/search_f/",
            data: {
                'search_text': $('#search').val(),
                'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()
            },
            success: searchSuccess,
            dataType: 'html'
        });
    });
});

function searchSuccess(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
{
    $('#search-results').html(data);
}


$('#search-results').typeahead({
    name: 'user-search',
    remote: '/posts/search_f/%QUERY' // you can change anything but %QUERY
});
```

I also need it to to be done so I won't get an error like this

```
Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience.
```

I recently spent hours trying to resolve this on google chrome only to have it resolove itself

EDIT

I did some research and even though it didn't work I feel like I'm on the right track

```
$(function() {
$("#search").typeahead({
    source:function(query,process) {
        $.ajax({
            url:'posts/search_f',
            type:'GET',
            data: {
            'search_text': $('#search').val(),
            'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()
        },
            //dataType: 'JSON',
            async: true,
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data)
            }
        })
    }
  })
});
```